# Symfony 2 setup error

Tags: php, symfony

I try to install symfony 2 via composer

```
$ composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition path-to-install
```

but I`m getting this

```
Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap handling the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception
```

I try to  to remove the /bin and /vendor folders of my project.

Then make a composer install, but I`m getting this error again

Thanks

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: try it with `-vvv` for verbosity so you can see more info on the error.

Comment: I had a similar error on using HHVM.

Comment: Checking your composer.json file is a good start point to handle the problem. There is a post-update-cmd configuration setting inside it from which you can remove some commands to check if it helps.